# Maximize power to RL with LM741 output

Tags: operational-amplifier, design, speakers, non-inverting

I have to design a circuit that maximizes power to RL which is a resistance representing a speaker attached to the end of a LM741 op-amp. This is a non-inverting op amp in the circuit, and I just need a generalized explanation of what to do to get the maximum power to (or dissipated in) RL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the [closed loop] output impedance equal RL. If the speaker is inductive, as in real life, it gets more complicated as you want power factor correction essentially by having an output impedance that is the complex conjugate of the load. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_transfer_theorem